# How can I unmask the first name and email address on Microsoft clarity of people who visit my checkout page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I linked my Wordpress website to Microsoft clarity in order to manage and see how users are interacting with my website. Now when users insert their first name and username in the input boxes field of the checkout (the plug-in that I’m using for checkout is cart flow, its responsible for managing the form fields) the information that they have added is masked when viewing it through “recording feature” of Microsoft clarity, even though I tried a variety solutions that I mentioned in the bottom to unmask the information they provided

**For anyone asking why i want to unmask, its just to give me a more in depth analysis of users who are facing difficulties signing up or buying a specific product **

Things I've done to unmask form input fields:

1- Added a parent CSS class selector for the the form. (doesn't work)

2- Added input & select selectors as umasked (doesn't' work)

3- Added `data-clarity-unmask="true"` to a parent div of the form (doesn't work)

The only think I haven't tried is adding `data-clarity-unmask="true"` to each individual form input. I'd have to modify the form plugin's code so I was trying to avoid that.

Any possible solutions to this problem ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue, we cannot guess what the relevant code is. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.